# Stop Click event after Dragging on Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, webflow

I’ve been struggling to solve this for days now. There is a slider with clickable items at the bottom of the page. I’ve made the slider draggable. But the issue is that when the dragging stops the click action also happens on the item on which mousedown event happened. I’ve tried to adding ‘pointer-vents: none’ to the inner item after dragging starts, but in this case draggint doesn’t work at all. Any ideas on how can I solve this problem?

https://duolutions-wondrous-site.webflow.io/straudo-branding-naming

Read-Only link of webflow: https://preview.webflow.com/preview/duolutions-wondrous-site?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=duolutions-wondrous-site&preview=9e5312190b70be978f65b8da04fbcefc&pageId=6377be41955fe23fb7c4bf33&workflow=preview

```
<script>
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;
const slider = document.querySelector('.items');

const end = () => {
    isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
}

const start = (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;   
}

const move = (e) => {
    if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const dist = (x - startX);
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - dist;
}

(() => {
    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', start);
    slider.addEventListener('touchstart', start);

    slider.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
    slider.addEventListener('touchmove', move);

    slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', end);
    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', end);
    slider.addEventListener('touchend', end);
})();


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no link to a working sandbox, so I can't be sure it will help, but I've noticed you didn't use Event.stopPropagation(). This should stop the propagation of the current event. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)